# Facing Grammar Issues / copywriterly and grammarly

Tags: grammar

if used (While, As, Which, If, Where, Because) Must use ! or ? or ,

When I did that it dropped 2% in grammarly, is there's specific conditions to put the ( ! , ? ) after this capital words? or every time?

As copywriterly advised to put them, then the result on grammarly went more bad.

Thank you all for answering

Comment: I think you should totally stop using those things (i.e., grammarly and copywriterly). They are misleading you and confusing you. I see more severe problems in your sentences than the ending punctuation marks. These errors are not pointed out by those things. For example: *"When the British engineer John Turtle Wood began searching."* is not a complete sentence, and neither is *" When the 80-year-old bishop tried to halt a procession in honor of the goddess Diana. By preaching the gospel."* Dictionaries are always a great help to learn how to construct sentences properly.

Comment: The above is just my opinion. And this is too - read books, newspapers, or online news.

Comment: that's the full please advise if still looks an issue :
Timothy was the pastor in Ephesus. When the 80-year-old bishop tried to halt a procession in honor of the goddess Diana. By preaching the gospel. The angry pagans beat him, dragged him through the streets, and stoned him to death.
Second one :
When the British engineer John Turtle Wood began searching. To find the remains of the Temple of Artemis. He succeeded in identifying its location.

Comment: This is outrageous. Who is putting in those full-stops/periods in between those sentences - Grammarly or Copywriterly? The sentence is *"When the 80-year-old bishop tried to halt a procession in honor of the goddess Diana [comma] **b**y preaching the gospel [comma] **t**he angry pagans beat him, dragged him through the streets, and stoned him to death. "*. Use commas in those places and not full-stops.

Comment: the stops suggested by hemingwayapp to make it readable for 11 - 13 years old

Thank you very much will do that, so the main thing is don't follow this 3 type of recommendations, the two listed above the hemingwayapp one

Answer (score 3):

Computer programs are stupid. They are like bad students who look only at superficial features of words, algebra problems, exam questions, etc. to try to pass exams without learning the subject. Taking advice from one of those computer programs is like taking advice from one of those bad students.

Don't worry about whether a sentence's score increases or decreases when you change something. Those numbers only reflect the numerical weights attached to the superficial criteria that the computer program considers, not clarity or meaningfulness to a human reader or appropriateness to the traditions of the language.

Comment: understood, thank you very very much

Answer (score 0):

It seems that an error in your writing is to write sentence fragments. Here are some examples of fragments:

> When the British engineer John Turtle Wood began searching.
>
> When the 80-year-old bishop tried to halt a procession in honor of the goddess Diana.

These are punctuated as sentences, but they are not sentences. They are adverbial phrases that describe a time.  A complete sentence could be:

> When John finishes eating, I will wash his plate.

But "When John finishes eating." is not a correct or complete sentence; it is a fragment. These errors are confusing the computer system that is checking your work. It applies an algorithm which can identify many common errors. But if it entirely fails to parse your sentence, it tends to assume that you must be writing in fragments on purpose. Grammarly and friends are useful tools, but not a substitute for learning grammar and carefully checking your work.

Comment: that's the full please advise if still looks an issue : Timothy was the pastor in Ephesus. When the 80-year-old bishop tried to halt a procession in honor of the goddess Diana. By preaching the gospel. The angry pagans beat him, dragged him through the streets, and stoned him to death. Second one : When the British engineer John Turtle Wood began searching. To find the remains of the Temple of Artemis. He succeeded in identifying its location..

Comment: Timothy is the old bishop in the sentence

Comment: If you need to change your question, please edit your question.  You should not post clarification of your question as a comment on my answer.... Your paragraphs are very badly punctuated. This prevents Grammarly from parsing them.